# How to use Matlab image processing toolbox Hough transform for detecting not just lines and circles?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I'm working on an image processing project with Matlab. I know about houghlines and houghcircle functions but I want to detect other things too with Hough transform. For example I want to detect a specific curve or ellipse or something like that.

Is there a simple solution? Can someone show me an example code for the problem? It's not necessary to use Hough transform but I think that's the most promising idea.

Comment: No, even circle detection is hard enough. You'd better use correlation (if your sample don't rotate/scale) or tree-like control point searching (for any kind of matrix coordinate transform).

Comment: this is called [Generalised Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform). There are a few MATLAB implmenentations online...

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I'll look up Generalised Hough transform.

Comment: The issue with Ellipse detection is the size of the accumulator table. It becomes 5-dimensional unless you do some things to reduce the number of values.